# Change font-color on page load not just on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header that I'm pulling in for each page of my site with an include, the header has a set font-color of black, but on some of my pages I have hero images with the header background transparency at 0 on load, I need the color to be changed to white when the page loads and then to black once I scroll,

I have to change the .svg sources to black versions when I scroll and keep white initially also, they also don't start off white.

Once I scroll down and then back to the top it works, but I'm not sure how to get it to start off white - I tried adding .onload in some way but it didn't work how I had it, any help is appreciated!

```
// Image Elements of Header

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var initialSrcProfile = "assets/images/profileicon-white.svg";
var scrollSrcProfile = "assets/images/profileicon-black.svg";
var initialSrcLogo = "assets/images/logo-white.png";
var scrollSrcLogo = "assets/images/logo-black.png";

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (value > 10)
  $(".profile-icon").attr("srcset", scrollSrcProfile);
    else
  $(".profile-icon").attr("srcset", initialSrcProfile);

        if (value > 10)
  $(".logo").attr("src", scrollSrcLogo);
    else
  $(".logo").attr("src", initialSrcLogo);

});
});

// Text Elements of Header

$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll > 0) {
  $(".navwrap a span").css("color", "black");
  $("#login-break").css("color", "black");
} if (scroll < 1) {
  $(".navwrap a span").css("color", "white");
  $("#login-break").css("color", "white");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is place your code for updating the header in a single function, then call that function on document ready AND on scroll. If it is in one function, then you can just use that single function for both.

```
let updateHeader = function() {

  var initialSrcProfile = "assets/images/profileicon-white.svg";
  var scrollSrcProfile = "assets/images/profileicon-black.svg";
  var initialSrcLogo = "assets/images/logo-white.png";
  var scrollSrcLogo = "assets/images/logo-black.png";

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  // Image Elements of Header
  if (scroll > 10) {
    $(".profile-icon").attr("srcset", scrollSrcProfile);
    $(".logo").attr("src", scrollSrcLogo);
  } else {
    $(".profile-icon").attr("srcset", initialSrcProfile);
    $(".logo").attr("src", initialSrcLogo);
  }

  // Text Elements of Header
  if (scroll > 0) {
    $(".navwrap a span").css("color", "black");
    $("#login-break").css("color", "black");
  }
  if (scroll < 1) {
    $(".navwrap a span").css("color", "white");
    $("#login-break").css("color", "white");
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  updateHeader();
  $(window).scroll(updateHeader);
});
```

It is possible that the browser will load the default colors first, display them, and then run the script to update them. This could cause some sort of flash, but it will be really quick most of the time. If that is an issue, then you want to make sure the initial CSS styles it exactly as you want it on load. I'm afraid that is probably the best you'll get.

Comment: Thanks works great! does have a bit of a flash to begin with but not worth bothering about really, is there any best practices for speed? do you know if it loads faster inside a html script tag or is it just as fast being included as a header.js file?

Comment: That's a big question, and the answer is: it depends. If it is in the document, it will load at the same time as the document, so any lag will effect the entire page and be strictly from the size increase of the document. If the script is in another file and loaded with async, then you don't know when it will arrive and run. Generally this will be better because if the user has enough bandwidth, he can download both at the same time, which might be faster. Plus, you get the benefit of reuse and caching.